# How can I launch IPython Notebook quietly on Windows?

Tags: windows, ipython, jupyter-notebook

When I start IPython notebook from the start menu item generated by the installation, it spawns a terminal window running the server. Can I somehow make the server run in the background so I don't need to have this "useless" window around? I tried various tips found online involving changing the shortcut to use pythonw.exe instead of python.exe, but none of them seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
pythonw -m IPython notebook
```

Seems a bit tricky though, since you won't notice whether the server is running or not.

Comment: Thanks! I added the following as "Target:" for a shortcut and now get the requested behaviour!
`"C:\Users\a0132634\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\pythonw.exe" -m IPython notebook`